# Displaying comments of a page without allowing new comments

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-comments

I've been using the facebook comments plugin to allow users to display comments on one of my pages.
Now I want to keep showing the already written comments without showing the form to post new comments, I don't want users to be able to write new comments, but just to read the old ones.

Is this possible?

If this is not possible, is there any snippet to read all the comments from the graph and displaying them in a page?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Comments Plugin documentation says how do to this, though the use-case there is for embedding the comments in a hidden div so search engines can crawl the comments

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ - the section marked **How do I access the comments left on my site?** explains how to do it and links to some sample code

Comment: I read it, but how can I print the comments, for example with javascript? I just have a huge string in that way...

Comment: What have you tried? it's returned back in JSON format so you should be able to parse it in javascript and then re-output it in whatever format you want

Comment: An example of how to parse it with javascript?